# Should UI components ever be passed to a Business Logic assembly for binding

Tags: c#, asp.net, architecture

I've recently been handed a code base which does a few things I'm a little different to how I usually do them.

The main difference is that it seems to pass elements (say for example a drop down list control) down to the business logic layer (in this case a separate project but still in the same solution) where the binding to business data takes place.

My natural approach is always to surface the information that is required up to the UI and bind there.

I'm struggling to match the first technique to any of the standard patterns but that may be down to the actual implementation less than the idea of what it is doing.

Has anyone ever encountered this type of architecture before? If so can you explain the advantages?

The solution is an ASP.Net website. Thanks.

Thanks,

Comment: Thanks guys,

All answers were great and confirmed what I was thinking. It's jut the second time I've seen something like this and wondered of there was perhaps a reason. I guess two people can be wrong in the same way :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would make the case that this is a bad architecture, since the original developer tightly coupled the business logic to the presentation layer. If you wanted to switch from webforms to, say, MVC, you'd have to refactor chunks of your business layer, which shouldn't be the case!

If it's at all possible, you should consider moving away from developing the site in this fashion. In the interim, you can at least start the decoupling process by splitting the logic up a little bit further. If, say, you have a `BindDropDown(DropDownList ddl)` method, split the method apart, so you have a `GetDropDownData()` method that returns your actual business object, and `BindDropDown` *only* sets the values of the DropDownList. That way, at least, you'll be more easily able to move away from the tight coupling of the presentation layer and business layer in the future.

Of course, if the site is already designed like that (with a clear demarcation between the presentation layer, the intermediate "presentation binding" layer, and the business layer), I could see a case being made that it's acceptable. It doesn't sound like that's the case, however.

Comment: I'm afraid it's something that I've inherited but I agree with the approach that you're suggesting. It's the same as how I would tackle it.

Answer (score 1):

No, you should **not** pass UI elements to the Domain Model to bind / Populate.

Your domain model should ideally be able to be used with Windows Forms / WPF / Silverlight / ASP.NET / MVC you name it.

Now, I kinda understand the idea that your business objects should know how to store and render themselves etc it's the OO holy grail, but in practice this doesn't work well, as there often are dependencies (database middleware, UI components etc) with those functions, that you do not want in your BO assembly, it severely limits your reusablility.

Something that you can do though that gives your users the illusion of your BO knowing how to render itself is using extension classes (in a separate assembly, to contain the dependencies) something like...

```
public static class AddressUIExtensions
{
  public static void DisplayAddress(this Address add, AddressControl control)
  {
     ...
  }
}
```

Then the API user can simply do

```
var ctrl = new AddressControl();
address.DisplayAddress(ctrl);
```

but you still have physical separation.

Answer (score 0):

> Has anyone ever encountered this type of architecture before?
>   If so can you explain the advantages?

The only advantage is speed of development - in the short-term; so it's well suited to simple apps, proof-of-concepts (PoC), etc.

Implementing proper abstraction usually takes time and brings complexity.  Most of the time that is what you really want, but sometimes an app might be built as a simple throw-away PoC.

In such cases it isn't so much that a room full of people sit down and debate architectures for a couple of hours and arrive at the decision that binding in the BL makes sense - it's usually a "whatever-gets-it-done-fastest" call by the developers based on speed.

Granted, that simple laziness or ignorance will probably be the reason why it's used in other cases.

Answer (score 0):

Your business layer should return a model - view model that the UI layer will in turn use to populate what it needs - period. There should be nothing sent to the business layer in terms of ui components - period. Its that simple and that hard and fast of a rule.